# IIS 8 (Server 2012) Site Binding Not Working Works When No Site Name Is Specified

Tags: ssl, iis, amazon-ec2, iis-8

I've run into a strange problem. If I put a site name in the site bindings, the Default Web Site on ISS is not recognizing it. Suppose I leave it blank, then I'm able to get the pages but they show up with the server IP address.

This is a problem because with SSL, it will either not serve pages or it will give me a site warning.

Note that I have the DNS working of GoDaddy with forwarding and masking to the public IP of my EC2 instance on AWS.

All of this started overnight when the SSL cert expired. I have since put a new certificate that's valid but I cannot get the site working again.

I've done a lot of debugging including diffing the old configuration that was working with the new one and I'm not able to understand why this happens.

Setting the site name causes both http and https to not work.

Much appreciate any help in solving this - Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be a problem with masking with forwarding provided by the domain host Go-Daddy. For some reason, with masking with forwarding, the response is enclosed in a frame and that frame says the src is the public IP address of the server rather than the domain name.

I also think that there is a problem with https forwarding with masking. While the reason this problem happened is not clear, for now, the fix has been to change the domain from masking with forwarding for http requests alone to point at the http server public IP address.

This is not the ideal solution but at least has the website back up and running. I'll post an update once I know more about masking with forwarding and why that suddenly stopped working.